# What is the pKa of choline chloride?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, acid-base, alcohols

I am looking for the pKa of choline chloride, which should be higher than 7 (around 10?), but I cannot find any reference value.

[image: choline chloride structure]

Comment: According to [the European Chemical Agency](https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/5360/4/22) you can conclude, ignoring most of the lengthy and somewhat strange analysis and focusing on the choline group, that pKa =10.6 at 25 °C (predicted "using the OASIS Consensus").

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/5289/4/22) a $p\mathrm{K_a}$ of 11.2 is reported, making the cation a slightly weaker acid than hydrogen cyanide, but pretty strong for an alcohol.

Comment: We have an ionic compound. We would expect the cation to have tge same pKa regardless of the counterion.

Comment: Yet tge pKa of the anion in your example remains the same. The choline cation will behave similarly.